# Dotnetnuke Skin

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

I developed dotnetnuke skin. In my localhost both login and logoff time skin was working fine all images and skin.css file was loading. but in my live site logoff time skin.css file and images are not loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you deployed the CSS files in production.

Check to make sure that the "paths" are correct, if you have any Includes in the CSS make sure that they are the proper path for production.

Post more details about what you are doing, what code, what errors, etc.

Comment: If I login as a admin my skin and its releated files loading properly.After logoff css file and skin related images are not loading. Folder permission was standard only.

Comment: Hi Chris We using DotNetNuke 6.2.3 enterprise edition. In localhost all images i referred in skin file was came both login and Logout Period.I followed the following steps.1st I need to create one child portal. so i went Host-->SiteManagement-->Add New Site--> i choosed the child portal and also site title,description,keywords.I can able to create child site. After that i went Admin-->SiteWizard-->Blank Template-->Replace Content-->I choosed my installed skin and Container in portal. Both Skin and HTML Contains image tag.Once i logout skin file not loaded due to that page alignment collapsed.